# can not get email when verify token_id from google account

Tags: android, python, email

I am building an app with google login. 
But in the server side, I receive a token id from android app, and I use google python oauth client to verify the token id, I can not receive the email of the user. How should I get the email?

Note: I have added the scope ["profile", "email"] in android app.

Here is the result:

```
{
    "iss":"accounts.google.com",
    "at_hash":"oYAefORrbLVw_7JJQzT2HX",
    "aud":"xxxx",
    "sub":"109021068515377007023",
    "azp":"xxxxxx",
    "iat":1439805196,
    "exp":1439808796,
    "name":"bob zhuang",
    "given_name":"bob",
    "family_name":"zhuang",
    "locale":"zh-CN"
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @CoderP I used an authorization code to get access token, after getting token, I used token to get user info.